# Problema al programar estrategia para ganar en el juego Battleship

Tags: java, poo

Soy estudiante y me mandaron a realizar una estrategia para ganar el juego Battleship,que consiste realizar disparos al azar, pero una vez que se ha alcanzado parte de un barco, comienza a buscar arriba , abajo , izquierda y derecha en busca de más del mismo barco.

Pero mi problema va que al momento de su ejecución este se detiene en medio de la búsqueda aun sin encontrar todos los barcos.

Creo que el problema esta en el método Target, pero no se en que lugar exactamente.

Para un mejor entendimiento dejare el código, espero que me puedan ayudar.

````
public class Tablero{ //Crea el tablero (No tengo permitido modificar esta clase).
    
  static java.util.Random generator = new java.util.Random();
  private char [][] t;
  private int intentos = 0;
  
  public Tablero(int n){
    if(n<10) n=10;
    t = new char[n+2][n+2];
    for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++)
      for(int j=1;j<n+1;j++)
        t[i][j]= '0';
    while(!ubicarNave(5,'A'));
    //Imprimir();
    while(!ubicarNave(4,'B'));
    //Imprimir();
    while(!ubicarNave(3,'C'));
    //Imprimir();
    while(!ubicarNave(3,'S'));
    //Imprimir();
    while(!ubicarNave(2,'D'));
    intentos = 0;
  }
  public char disparo(int x, int y){
    intentos++;
    if(x<1 || x>t.length) return 0;
    if(y<1 || y>t.length) return 0;
    char aux = t[x][y];
    if(aux!= '0') t[x][y]='X';
    return aux;
  }
  private boolean ubicarNave(int l, char tipo){
    int x = 1+generator.nextInt(t.length-2);
    int y = 1+generator.nextInt(t.length-2);
    int dir = generator.nextInt(4);
    if(dir==0 && x-(l-1)<1) return false;
    if(dir==1 && x+(l-1)>t.length-1) return false;
    if(dir==2 && y-(l-1)<1) return false;
    if(dir==3 && y+(l-1)>t.length-1) return false;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
      if(dir==0 && (t[x-i][y]!='0' || t[x-i][y+1]!='0' || t[x-i][y-1]!='0')) return false;
      if(dir==1 && (t[x+i][y]!='0' || t[x+i][y+1]!='0' || t[x+i][y-1]!='0')) return false;
      if(dir==2 && (t[x][y-i]!='0' || t[x-1][y-i]!='0' || t[x+1][y-i]!='0')) return false;
      if(dir==3 && (t[x][y+i]!='0' || t[x-1][y+i]!='0' || t[x+1][y+i]!='0')) return false;
    }
    if(dir==0 && t[x-(l)][y]!='0') return false;
    if(dir==1 && t[x+(l)][y]!='0') return false;
    if(dir==2 && t[x][y-(l)]!='0') return false;
    if(dir==3 && t[x][y+(l)]!='0') return false;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
      if(dir==0) t[x-i][y]=tipo;
      if(dir==1) t[x+i][y]=tipo;
      if(dir==2) t[x][y-i]=tipo;
      if(dir==3) t[x][y+i]=tipo;
    }
    return true;
  }
  public int ganar(){
    for(int i=1;i<t[0].length-1;i++)
      for(int j=1;j<t.length-1;j++)
        if(t[i][j]!='0' && t[i][j]!='X') return 0;
    //Imprimir();
    return intentos;
  }
  public void Imprimir(){
    for(int i=1;i<t[0].length-1;i++){
      for(int j=1;j<t.length-1;j++)
        System.out.print(t[i][j] + " ");
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}
//********************************************************************************
 //Busca en donde estan los barcos  
 public int Buscarbarcos (){
       
        char disp ;
       
        Random aleatorio = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ //llena la matriz con 0
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
               tablero_aux[i][j] = 0; 
            }
        }
        
        
        while(num_aciertos < 17 ){
            
            int fila = aleatorio.nextInt(10)+1;//valor aleatorio del 1 al 10
            int col = aleatorio.nextInt(10)+1; 
            
          
                    
                    if(tablero_aux[fila][col] != 0){//si ya se reviso la posicion
                        continue;
                    }else{ //si no se reviso
                        tablero_aux[fila][col] = 1;
                         disp = t.disparo(fila, col);
                         
                        //si acierta un barco
                        if(disp != '0'){
                           
                         num_aciertos ++;
                         Target(disp,fila,col);//la funcion target es la que se queda pegada
                     
                         
                         if(num_aciertos == 17){

                           return t.ganar();
                           
                         }
                      
                        }
                        
                    }
           
              
        }
        
        return t.ganar();
    }


    public int Target(char disp,int l,int k){
      
        //revisa a la isquierda
        boolean left = false;
        if(k-1 >= 0 && tablero_aux[l][k-1] == 0){
            
            tablero_aux[l][k-1] = 1;
            t.disparo(l, (k-1));
            disp = t.disparo(l, (k-1));
            if(disp != '0'){

              num_aciertos++;
              left = true;
            if(num_aciertos == 17){
              return t.ganar();
             }
            }
            
        }
        
        if(left){
           seguir_busqueda = true;
           int num = 2;
           while(seguir_busqueda){
               if(k-num >= 0 && tablero_aux[l][k-num] == 0){
                   tablero_aux[l][k-num] = 1;
                   t.disparo(l, (k-num));
                   disp = t.disparo(l, (k-num));
                   
                   if(disp != '0'){

                     num_aciertos++; 
                     num++;
                     if(num_aciertos == 17){
                         return t.ganar();
                     }
                   }else{
                      seguir_busqueda = false; 
                   }
               }
           }
        }
        
        //revisa a la derecha
        boolean right = false;
        if(k+1 <= 10 && tablero_aux[l][k+1] == 0){
            tablero_aux[l][k+1] = 1;
            t.disparo(l, (k+1));
            disp = t.disparo(l, (k+1));
            if(disp != '0'){

              num_aciertos++;              
              right = true;
            if(num_aciertos == 17){
              return t.ganar();
             }
            }
            
        }
        
        if(right){
           seguir_busqueda = true;
           int num = 2;
           while(seguir_busqueda){
               if(k+num <= 10 && tablero_aux[l][k+num] == 0){
                   tablero_aux[l][k+num] = 1;
                   t.disparo(l, (k+num));
                   disp = t.disparo(l, (k+num));
                   
                   if(disp != '0'){

                     num_aciertos++; 
                     num++;
                     
                     if(num_aciertos == 17){
                         return t.ganar();
                     }
                   }else{
                      seguir_busqueda = false; 
                   }
               }
           }
        }
        //revisa arriba
        
        boolean up = false;
        if(l-1 >= 0 && tablero_aux[l-1][k] == 0){
            tablero_aux[l-1][k] = 1;
            t.disparo((l-1), k);
            disp = t.disparo((l-1), k);
            if(disp != '0'){

              num_aciertos++;               
              up = true;
            if(num_aciertos == 17){
              return t.ganar();
             }
            }
            
        }
        
        if(up){
           seguir_busqueda = true;
           int num = 2;
           while(seguir_busqueda){
               if(l-num >= 0 && tablero_aux[l-num][k] == 0){
                   tablero_aux[l-num][k] = 1;
                   t.disparo((l-num), k);
                   disp = t.disparo((l-num), k);
                   
                   if(disp != '0'){

                     num_aciertos++; 
                     num++;
                     
                     if(num_aciertos == 17){
                         return t.ganar();
                     }
                   }else{
                      seguir_busqueda = false; 
                   }
               }
           }
        }
        //revisa abajo
        
        boolean down = false;
        if(l+1 <= 10 && tablero_aux[l+1][k] == 0){
            tablero_aux[l+1][k] = 1;
            t.disparo((l+1), k);
            disp = t.disparo((l+1), k);
            if(disp != '0'){

              num_aciertos++;        
              down = true;
            if(num_aciertos == 17){
              return t.ganar();
             }
            }
            
        }
        
        if(down){
           seguir_busqueda = true;
           int num = 2;
           while(seguir_busqueda){
               if(l+num <= 10 && tablero_aux[l+num][k] == 0){
                   tablero_aux[l+num][k] = 1;
                   t.disparo((l+num), k);
                   disp = t.disparo((l+num), k);
                   
                   if(disp != '0'){

                     num_aciertos++; 
                     num++;
                     
                     if(num_aciertos == 17){
                         return t.ganar();
                     }
                   }else{
                      seguir_busqueda = false; 
                   }
               }
           }
        }
        
    
    

        return 0;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Por qué tienes 5 bucles `while` sin nada dentro??? Por otro lado, el código que pasaste está incompleto y obviamente no compila así que va a ser difícil que alguien te sepa decir qué está pasando solo con mirar las **300** líneas de código que pusiste ahí... Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y hagas el [tour], y proporciones un [mre] para poder depurar tu código, pues "*se detiene en medio de la búsqueda aun sin encontrar todos los barcos*" deja claro que es un error de lógica, y no tenemos acceso a la lógica del programa puesto que ni compila!

Comment: De todas maneras, intuyo que el problema está en que en el momento que uno de esos `while` devuelve `false` nunca vas a salir de ahí, puesto que dentro del bucle no hace absolutamente nada

Comment: @ Benito-B a que `while` te refieres??Porque los que se encuentran en la clase Tablero no los puedo modificar ya que a base de esta clase debo solucionar el problema.